# Mirror element using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it's possible to "mirror" some node to another place in the dom , for example lets say we have an `<iframe>`  that's displaying a webpage with multiple images in it , i can select each img using the contentDocument property but can i do this via css? so the img tag will remain in the iframe but will be displayed somewhere else in the dom.

Comment: no, css can't effect things inside an iframe.

Comment: @CarolMcKay i don't need to effect things inside an iframe , i need to mirror iframe nodes to the main dom

Comment: css + iframe = no

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do? Copy an image from one place to another in the DOM? That is not called mirroring, by the way.

Comment: @MrLister No i'm not trying to copy the image , I'm trying to mirror the img node to lets say a div node in the main dom , so the div will contain the img but only via css the real node is inside the iframe , so no further request for the img src